# Should the "Differences" tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tagging

6 questions tagged. People have used it to ask about differences between similar ingredients and end products as well as differences in cooking methods.

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differences

Answer (score 3):

This tag seems useless. Who would search specifically for or follow questions specifically about the differences between two things?

I like Aaronut's rule of thumb,

> If you can't look at a tag and honestly say "somebody's probably
>   written a book about this" then it shouldn't exist as a tag.

Comment: Yep, I agree. The tag looks useless to me.

Comment: There are so few instances that you could just remove yourself, I think. I'm guessing that on most of the rare occasions this might be useful, [tag:substitutions] might apply anyway.

Comment: @Jefromi I was going to just kill them myself but it's been a while since I've done something like that. I mentioned it in chat and was pointed this way. Figured checking consensus was better safe than sorry.

Comment: Yup, it's good you checked, I'm just saying now that you know, go for it. (If it were a lot we might do it differently to avoid flooding the front page.)